# frair_boot() returning warning - Extreme quantiles used. Intervals will be unstable

Tags: r, bootstrapping

I attempted to bootstrap my functional response data for my masters project. I am looking at how body size affects the functional response! For the 'big' crayfish the bootstrapping returned very normal confidence intervals with no warnings. For the 'small' crayfish I got this warning : ' Note 1: Warning: Extreme quantiles used. Intervals will be unstable!'

Have I done something wrong in my code? The data is structured the same and has the same repeats as the 'big' data. Here is the code for the 'small' data:

```
set.seed(42)
# Bootstrap the small data
smallIIb <- frair_boot(smallII)
confint(smallIIb, citypes = 'bca')

BOOTSTRAPPING.
NB: This function calls the lambertW function. Please be patient.
Coefficient  CI Type        Lower   Upper   Notes   
a            BCa            1.314   193.615 1
h            BCa            0.014   0.031   1
Note 1: Warning: Extreme quantiles used. Intervals will be unstable!
```

This was the 'big' data which returned normal CIs. Just totally confused as to what has happened.

So as you can see the 'big' data below has returned normal CIs and the 'small' one above hasn't. Can I fix this?

```
set.seed(42)
# Bootstrap the big data
bigIIb <- frair_boot(bigII)
confint(bigIIb, citypes = 'bca')


BOOTSTRAPPING.
NB: This function calls the lambertW function. Please be patient.
Coefficient  CI Type        Lower   Upper   
a            BCa            3.418   9.193   
h            BCa            0.007   0.012
```

Answer (score 0):

The BCa intervals are also quantile intervals, it is just that unlike the conventional quantile intervals, which take the `(alpha/2, 1-(alpha/2))` interval, it takes the `(alpha1, alpha2)` interval where:

[image]
 
The bias correction is: 
[image]

The fraction represents the proportion of times the bootstrap statistic is smaller than the original statistic estimated on the full data and that proportion is then used as input to the normal distribtution quantile function.  There is also an acceleration constant:

[image]

which corrects the bootstrap sample for skewness.  The T with an (i) subscript is the jackknifed value of the statistic being bootstrapped and the T with a (.) subscript is the average of all the jackknifed T values.

The result are `alpha1` and `alpha2`.  The warning is telling you that those values are very far out in the tails, where `alpha1` is approaching the minimum value and/or `alpha2` is approaching the maximum value of the bootstrapped statistics.  The warning is an indication that these values out in the tails are unstable in repeated sampling.  If you rant the bootstrap algorithm again, you might end up with quite different confidence intervals.

The main question is can you fix it.  Maybe, if you could update the question with your code and data, we could perhaps help you figure something out.  As a first guess, I wonder if you've got some outliers that are problematic or if you've got a skewed variable that might be amenable to a non-linear transformation (e.g., log, Box-Cox)?  Anything you could do to reduce the skewness of the bootstrapped statistic distribution would likely help.